# REST API : Passing Colon (:) in url using attribute Routing doesn't work

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core, swagger-ui

I am using swagger ui to test a POST method. I am passing the parameter in URL but it doesn't work. 
swagger-ui:

> I enter this 
>  Date: 2017-03-03T12:12:12 
>  this is how it goes
>   in 
>  url: https://*servername*/Results/2017-03-03T12%3A12%3A12

This doesn't work. it return 404 error
but when i pass just the date it works.

> Date: 2017-03-03

my method:

> [Route("{Results/{date}"), HttpPost]
>  public
>   Common.CallDetails StartTCISCall(DateTime date)

I have tried this also but it doesn't even catch it as a string.

> [Route("{Results/{*date}"), HttpPost]
>  public
>   Common.CallDetails StartTCISCall(string date)

as soon as i take the colons out it starts to work. What can i do?

Also, for my friend it works locally on VS but when he publishes to IIS it doesn't work and we tried 3 different servers. Why is this?

Many thanks, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out that it was an IIS issue where the server is configured to deny : or % so that's why the encoded URL wasn't getting through either**.

**After changing the settings on IIS it works.**

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I am having a similar problem I have code that passes a timestamp that the user enters to a string variable that is actually an SQL query. When the SQL query gets executed it doesn't work because the colons were changed into percentages. I see that you had a similar problem I don't understand from you answer how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems like encoded URLs only work, after the ? for global variables, according to this: [URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17790994/7729014). So it won't work for routing in c#.

For encoded strings after the question mark u have to decode the string like this:

```
string result = Server.UrlDecode(date);
```

Your URL should be build like this:

```
https://servername/Results?2017-03-03T12%3A12%3A12
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Because it doesn't hit the function if colons are used.If it hits the function then i can decode it.

Comment: Even when i try to capture the parameter in a string it doesn't hit the function. Those : and %3A are causing 404 error.

Comment: oh okay... seems like this won't work. - you only can encode the URL after the ? according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790994/7729014

Comment: yeah, I don't why is it not hitting the function and as soon as i take the time  part out of datetime and just pass in date. it works.